# What to store in redux state?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm building a medium-sized React/Redux app, and I've become very comfortable with React - however, Redux is still a little hard to wrap my head around.

I understand that I can use  `connect()` from Redux to connect any Component or Container to Redux state. However, I'm unclear on when to do this - is it based on complexity? How many props would need to be passed down to child components?

What are the factors I can use to determine when to use `connect()`?

Edit to provide an example:  -----

For example, I'd like to include a messages area for users inside my app, particularly a badge showing number of unread messages. Would I simply `connect()` any component where I'd like to display the badge?

Comment: You store your app state in redux. ie, replace the usage of this.setState with your redux state.

Comment: I'm basically comfortable with that - but is the goal to simply never use `setState()` in a redux app? In any situation?

Comment: For most things, yeah. You don't have to eliminate it entirely, but any prop that needs to get passed to another component will be stored in redux instead and pulled from the redux state instead

Comment: I've seen this discussed, so my question ultimately is - do I just `connect()` every component? How can I know beforehand if I should `connect()`? I appreciate the responses.

Comment: There's nothing stopping you from using connect() where ever you need to. The general rule of thumb is that you have some high level components or containers that are stateful, these will use use connect(). They'll hook into your actions (mapDispatchToProps), and your redux store (mapStateToProps). You can then pass props or dispatch funcs to your child components.

Comment: That's helpful, I think I just need more experience with redux - thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You store the state of your app in redux. How you structure your state tree is up to you. You can think of the state tree as one giant javascript object. With redux, you would ideally store as little component state in your react components themselves and instead move that to the redux state tree.

For example, if you fetched some user data, you could store that in the redux state such that your connected components have access to that data now. You can also get more granular and store states that describe certain UI components. A part of your state that describes a dropdown could look like this

```
{
  myDropdown: {
    isOpen: false,
    options: [
      'apple',
      'orange'
    ]
  }
}
```

I believe a good point to start incorporating redux is when your app gets to a certain point where your components are no longer just "dumb" components that display data.

Edit:
To try and answer the question "when should I connect my components?". I struggled with this myself but don't have a great answer yet. Right now I typically connect a component if I am passing down props through many ancestor components just for that component specifically. So connecting would avoid that boilerplate code altogether.

Comment: This is helpful - although I guess I'm finding it hard to wrap my head around the idea of a giant object full of tiny details like this. Many articles on the subject say that it's hard to know when to use redux state or local state, I was hoping there was a clearer answer - many thanks.

Comment: For the most part if you have a react-redux app I would avoid local state entirely unless you can trying to solve a very component specific problem. For example I would use local state if my component does something on a setInterval and so it is keeping its own timer.

Comment: You may also want to check out the relevant answer in the Redux FAQ: http://redux.js.org/docs/FAQ.html#organizing-state-only-redux-state .  Basically, find a balance between local stand and Redux state that works for you.

Answer (score 39):

I DON'T agree about storing all component state in the store. I prefer having in the redux store only data that matters to application as a whole and thus other components may benefit from this global accessible shared data.

Having component specific state in the store, that only matters to this component, is a overkill and useless IMO.

Comment: I back this. Putting UI state into Redux will only make it harder for yourself to manage state. Your app will also become slow quickly as bad Redux implementations cause a ton of useless re-renders and components listening to Redux state changes which they shouldn't listen to.

Comment: Absolutely agree! Saving everything in global store complicates the application, makes it harder to find what's where.

Answer (score 6):

Official REDUX page:

https://redux.js.org/faq/organizing-state#do-i-have-to-put-all-my-state-into-redux-should-i-ever-use-reacts-setstate

Some common rules of thumb for determining what kind of data should be put into Redux:

1. Do other parts of the application care about this data?
2. Do you need to be able to create further derived data based on this original data?
3. Is the same data being used to drive multiple components?
4. Is there value to you in being able to restore this state to a given point in time
5. Do you want to cache the data
6. List item

**But...that means in most of off applications the only data what I should store in Redux store is the logged in user data.** That is the only entity which attributes influences all the screens (role, login name, user settings).

Usual applications do not need to remember entered data between screens, cache, history....

*Very confusing, so I am not really sure any more what to put in Redux store...*

Comment: I have experienced first hand the pain that storing everything in Global State (Redux) brings. By default, you should put everything in the local component state unless you have a VERY good reason (If you can thoroughly answer all the points in this answer) to store it in the global state.